# Live boot USB username/password doesn't work Kali Linux

Tags: linux, login, liveusb

I've made a live USB of Kali Linux (latest amd64, using Rufus), and it boots up fine and everything, but when I try any of the live versions (I can install it fine, I would much more like to have it live though), it asks for my username/password, and when I type in root / toor or any other solutions I've found online, none worked.

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Your photos show "Progress Linux"? That doesn't seem like Kali Linux.

Comment: That's what's weird; when it boots up, it's the normal Kali Linux boot menu (Live USB, persistent USB, install, etc.), and I can install it fine, I just don't want to. **But**, when I click on any of the LIVE options, it throws me here.

Now this is what I don't understand.

Comment: Where did you download Kali from? https://www.kali.org/downloads/?

Comment: Yeah, the 64 bit version on top. kali-linux-2017.3-amd64.iso

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your download or USB key. When do the download and start it in a VM, "it just works"™.

Comment: I guess I'll re-download the .iso again; it works fine in a VM environment. I'm baffled. The USB should be fine, it's new. I've also flashed the .iso to it with the program that they suggested, but I got the same results, meh.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution below as it has worked for me -

- Select Other user
- Use root as the username
- Enter the root administrator password you entered during the install.

Comment: Problem here is; I don't want to install Kali, I want to use it live.

I don't even get to the normal login screen, this is the only screen I get after I select the live version. Hence why I can't "select other user".

Answer (score 0):

Either

Type in the terminal

```
sudo su
```

it will ask for your userpassword and make you root/superuser

Or chroot to the harddrive and change the password

(Note, recently kali Linux no longer uses a “root for everything model” meaning if your version  is new enough Sudo su may not work)

Answer (score -1):

The password is kali.
"kali" without the quotes...

Comment: If this answer is correct, I would think it would be the best one. The other two seem useless, seeing as they rely on already knowing some password.